# URL rewirte directory names

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, directory

I have my website directory like this:

- application
- assets
- system

And under application I got this:

- help
- contact

I created a file inside each one called index.php so the URL can look something like  [this](http://www.exaple.com/application/help), but I have seen so many websites with an URL like  [this](http://www.example.com/help), I've seen this is made with .htaccess file, but the problem is that I don't know where should I put it and how to set it up.

Would be nice if you put some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apache site has tons of examples.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

This isn't tested, but something like this should suffice.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /application/$1 [L,QSA]
```